# Visual Studio 2010 + ReSharper 5.1 Class Highlighting Problem

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have recently started using Visual Studio 2010 and ReSharper 5.1. It's working pretty well for me so far except for this one issue which I'm hoping someone has the answer for. Basically, like many others, I tend to use a dark colour scheme to improve readability over the default VS colour scheme. Having installed ReSharper I have noticed that when I navigate to a class name, the class name and any references to it get highlighted. That in itself is fine but with the colour scheme I've chosen, I'm getting a light-on-light combination which is unreadable.

I've gone through the Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors menu a few times but there doesn't seem to be an appropriate ReSharper item.

Here is a screenshot illustrating the highlighting problem
[image: Screenshot of highlighting problem]

Comment: I understand the need to customize colors and fonts, but I find it hard to stomach a Norton Commander slash VT100 Emulator style scheme. To each his own I guess.

Comment: @Allon Guralnek I started out coding in DOS using Borland Turbo Pascal 7 and [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) (using [RHIDE](http://www.rhide.com/)) so the dark blue colour scheme is what I'm used to. I can't handle staring at a white background and I find a black background too dark so the dark blue is a satisfactory compromise I reckon :-).

Also, being left-handed, I'm well used to doing things perceived as awkward by others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `Highlighted Reference` background color. It is not resharper one.

Comment: Ah, correct. It's the Highlighted Reference item. I thought it was ReSharper as I didn't do anything with VS2010 until I had it installed and I hadn't noticed that behaviour with 2008 (or if I did, I forgot about it)

Comment: @Malice. It is the only good way - to install Resharper right after VS :)